# Select special index with special attribute value

Tags: jquery, css, selector

consider this code:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="list">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>city</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td o="1">aaa</td>
        <td o="2">20</td>
        <td o="3">zzzzzzzz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td o="2">hhhhhhh</td>
        <td o="3">55</td>
        <td o="1">aaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td o="3">qqqqq</td>
        <td o="1">15</td>
        <td o="2">qq</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

how i can select ROW (TR) that contain TD with attribute (o=2) that appeare in **column N** ?!

i try this but don't work:

```
$("table#list tr").filter(':has(td:eq(0)[o="2"])')...
```

Comment: I don't remember seeing that attribute in the HTML spec.

Comment: replace "o" with "value" or any value you want! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("table#list tr").filter(function(){
  return $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)[o='2']").length > 0;
  //nth-child is indexed from 1
});
```

Comment: thanks. but if i want **n-child** instead of FIRST, how i can?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getNthChild(n) {
    return $('#list td:eq(' +n + ')[o="2"]').closest('tr');
}
```

jsfiddle:     http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/Bhtdr/3/

Comment: `$("#list tr").filter(':has(td[o="2"])')` is faster

Comment: The question said only cells in the _first_ column. This will select those that are in other columns too. There's no need to use `.filter` either - you can do everything in a single selector.

Comment: thanks Matt.
your code select TR that contain TD that have o=2 attribute
but i want TD with `o=2` attribute that **are N-index in it's TR**.

Comment: @Mrchief Because it's not the best solution. There's no need to filter the result and `:has` makes for weird, non-standard syntax.

Comment: @Matt: Just because there are other ways of doing things, doesn't mean it deserves a downvote. Anyway, I updated my answer as per OP's ask and it doesn't use `filter` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single selector:

```
$("table#list tr td:first-child[o=2]")..
```

Use `nth-child` to select cells with attribute `o="2"` in the second column, for example:

```
$("table#list tr td:nth-child(2)[o=2]")..
```

Comment: thanks. but if i want **n-child** instead of FIRST, how i can?!

Comment: Err.. by using `nth-child`? `$("table#list tr td:nth-child(1)[o=2]")`

Comment: Good!
this select TD and have completed with use `.closest('tr')` or `.parent()`. thanks.